# How to use sed to output lines containing odd numbers which contain an even digit?

Tags: sed

how do you use sed to output only lines which contain odd numbers which themselves contain an even digit assuming that each line only contains a number.

E.G.

```
seq 1000 | sed ...
```

Output ends with:

```
.
.
.
963
965
967
969
981
983
985
987
989
```

Comment: schoolwork? What have you tried so far? Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
seq 1000 | sed -n '/[24680].*[13579]$/ p'
```

This is essentially using sed to emulate grep. More direct, then:

```
seq 1000 | grep '[24680].*[13579]$'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
seq 1000 | sed -ne '/[02468]/ { /[13579]$/ p }'
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
 seq 1 1000 | sed '/[13579]\>/!d;/[02468]/!d'
```

Comment: I think he wants the two pass solution, first in which we do odd lines and then pipe it to another filter that displays lines which has even number.

Comment: @Jaypal thanks. I was too hasty! but this solution saves a second pass.

Comment: Yea it's way better than mine. :)